# error package org.apache.pig.FilterFunc not exist

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

May I ask a question please, I get Pig installed and configured, but it says "`error package org.apache.pig.FilterFunc not exist`" while I am trying to compile a very simple java source file by using javac command.

The CLASSPATH variable is set as listed below:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/:/usr/local/pig/lib/:.:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/lib/dt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/lib/tools.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar
```

and these two environment variables set as below:

```
export PIG_INSTALL=/usr/local/pig
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop
```

The source code of file IsUseragentBot.java is listed as below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.pig.FilterFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class IsUseragentBot extends FilterFunc {

    private Set<String> blacklist = null;

    private void loadBlacklist() throws IOException {
        blacklist = new HashSet<String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("blacklist"));
        String userAgent = null;
        while ((userAgent = in.readLine()) != null) {
            blacklist.add(userAgent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {
        if (blacklist == null) {
            loadBlacklist();
        }
        if (tuple == null || tuple.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        String ua = (String)tuple.get(0);
        if (blacklist.contains(ua)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;   
    }

}
```

While I am going to compile source file by executing javac IsUseragentBot.java,it always fails and says that "error package org.apache.pig not exist",could any buddy help me please,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, it is related to compatibility between pig and hadoop, besides the compilation of pig